# Doctrine file uploading error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-http-foundation

Ran into a strange problem - after submitting a form via POST with enctype="multipart/form-data", Doctrine crashes with Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '[PATH/TO/DOCTRINE]/Doctrine\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile.php' (include_path='.;H:\SERVER\php\PEAR') in [PATH/TO/DOCTRINE]\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.class.php on line 164
```

I don't use Symfony, but I use the Symfony HTTPFoundation and Doctrine separately. And it seems that the error happens when the code calls:

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
```

I don't understand what does Doctrine have to do with this line...

UPD. 
It wasn't autoloading the contents of Symfony HTTPFoundation "File" folder from HTTP Component, so once that was fixed it started working.
But why it was trying to access it via Doctrine Symfony component is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Nice to see a female php developer.